# What happens if a country omits the zeros of it's current money?

Tags: currency, money, government

I mean, for example, the government changes all x10000 to x1; where x equals to currency of the respected country (Dollar, for instance).

Comment: Nothing interesting. Its called redenomination and happens all the time:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redenomination .

Comment: Policy is a process. not an event.